# JAVA: Why can't I access a method in the same class?

Tags: java, methods, find, symbols

I can't seem to find out why my static method is not able to call other methods in the same class. What should I do?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.*;

    public class MashupII {

      public void Append(Sound clip, boolean rev, double scale){


        //Void methods...


            //main method
      public static void main (String [] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        clips = new Sound[100];

        System.out.println("Please enter your command (A, I, D, P or Q)");   
        char command = Character.toUpperCase(keyboard.next().charAt(0));

        while (command != 'Q'){
          switch (command){
            case 'A': 

              //APPENDING
              //pick the clip
              System.out.println("Please pick a file.");      
              Sound clip = new Sound(FileChooser.pickAFile());

              //reversing
              System.out.println("Would you like to reverse the clip? (Y|N)");
              String reverse = keyboard.nextLine();

              boolean rev = reverse.equalsIgnoreCase("Y");


              //scaling
              System.out.println("How much should the clip be scaled? (1 is no scaling)");
              double scale = keyboard.nextDouble();

              clips.Append(clip,rev,scale);

              break;
            case 'I':
              break;
            case 'D':
              System.out.println("Which clip would you like to delete? (1- end)");
              int p = keyboard.nextInt();
              clips.Delete(p);
              break;
            case 'P':
              break;
            default: 
              System.out.println("Error! Please enter one of the available commands (A, I, D, P or Q)");
          }
          System.out.println("Please enter another command (A, I, D, P or Q)");
          command = Character.toUpperCase(keyboard.next().charAt(0));
        }
      }
}
```

I get the error in the switch case. It gives me a symbol not found. Any help would be great!

Comment: which symbol is not found?

Comment: `clips.Append(clip,rev,scale);`... Clips is your sound array.

Comment: I don't see you using any method declared in `MashupII`.

Comment: agree.. @user1760791 please put proper code snippet.

Comment: Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clips is not an instance of your MashupII class, which is why you are not able to call MashupII's append() method.